# ORACLE APEX doesn´t pass ITEM to next page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

ORACLE APEX 20.2

I'm trying to pass the value of an Interactive grid column to a modal page. I created a page_item to receive the value and used a JavaScript action to load the column value via the selection change [interactive grid] event.

```
var i, selectedIds = "", model = this.data.model; 
for ( i = 0; i < this.data.selectedRecords.length; i++ ) 
  { apex.item("P8205_ID_MOD_SELECTED").setValue(model.getValue( this.data.selectedRecords[i], "ID")); }
```

It works. The data is loaded into page_item P8205_ID_MOD_SELECTED.

But, when I load a modal page passing the value of this page_item, the value doesn´t loads on the page.

Any idea?

Comment: did you try sending the value to session? you will need an apex.server.process if you are using JS to get the data APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('my_item','myvalue');

Comment: Did you check this blog ? https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/